# Why does the "no-unnecessary-conditions" rule get confused by "!!"?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

When adding the `@typescript-eslint/no-unneccessary-conditions` rule, we are getting many errors on code which appears correct.

The error message seems to be incorrect too.

What am I missing?

```js
type Foo = { foo: string }

export function myFunction(nullableThing: Foo | null) {
  if (!!nullableThing) { // <-- "Unnecessary conditional, value is always falsy"
    return 'foo'
  } else {
    return 'bar'
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not [reproduce the error](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.8.4&sourceType=module&code=C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAzBAuKBnYAJwEsA7AcygF8BYAKHogA8w5DhMBXUgY2GLikoAWxAxufAaQAUpTgBt5AQwBG8iABUAFmXK54iAD5Q5igJRp6UKMQxRpAQgenlazTooX0Aem9QAPAC0gVAARACqpKQQPBB4eEqEIFA8ggAmxPyCSvIANFAAbjmc0MR4UDkA7kog5Rg5eCChVtZQhBDAnIRCAORYcD0tVFAQ8njQqC3W7Z3dUD0qiYN01rR0VEA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6Jge1tiacTJTIAhtEK0yHJgBNK+SpPRRE0aB2iRwYAL4gtQA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA)

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Have you tried restarting your code editor? In vscode you can open the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P -> Eslint: Restart ESLint Server)

Comment: Thanks for this - you're right. An editor restart and suddenly it all starts making sense again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed as suggested by the comments - restarting the VS Code ESLint server

Answer (score -1):

Because your condition is always `truthy` or always `falsy`. For the `nullableThing` param, you have to pass either `type Foo` or `null` value.

`null` is `falsy` like:

- undefined
- NaN
- ""
- 0
- false

So it's not necessary to cas your param:

```js
if (!!nullableThing) {...}
```

Just use this below. Your condition will be true or false.

```js
if (nullableThing) {...}
```

[image]

Comment: What you are saying is accurate, but not relevant to the error in question. The error mentioned in the question should only occur when `X` in `if (X) { ... }` is always falsy, which shouldn't be the case for a union type where one of the options is an object.